# App does not build after upgrading to 3.0.0

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I got a problem with the [qr_code_scanner](https://pub.dev/packages/qr_code_scanner) library after upgrading my flutter to the new 3.0.0

```
e: /home/kalheeso/snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/qr_code_scanner-0.7.0/android/src/main/kotlin/net/touchcapture/qr/flutterqr/QRView.kt: (23, 1): Class 'QRView' is not abstract and does not implement abstract member public abstract fun onRequestPermissionsResult(p0: Int, p1: Array<(out) String!>, p2: IntArray): Boolean defined in io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.RequestPermissionsResultListener
e: /home/kalheeso/snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/qr_code_scanner-0.7.0/android/src/main/kotlin/net/touchcapture/qr/flutterqr/QRView.kt: (216, 26): Null can not be a value of a non-null type String
e: /home/kalheeso/snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/qr_code_scanner-0.7.0/android/src/main/kotlin/net/touchcapture/qr/flutterqr/QRView.kt: (247, 26): Null can not be a value of a non-null type String
e: /home/kalheeso/snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/qr_code_scanner-0.7.0/android/src/main/kotlin/net/touchcapture/qr/flutterqr/QRView.kt: (310, 5): 'onRequestPermissionsResult' overrides nothing
e: /home/kalheeso/snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/qr_code_scanner-0.7.0/android/src/main/kotlin/net/touchcapture/qr/flutterqr/QRViewFactory.kt: (10, 1): Class 'QRViewFactory' is not abstract and does not implement abstract base class member public abstract fun create(p0: Context?, p1: Int, p2: Any?): PlatformView defined in io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformViewFactory
e: /home/kalheeso/snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/qr_code_scanner-0.7.0/android/src/main/kotlin/net/touchcapture/qr/flutterqr/QRViewFactory.kt: (13, 5): 'create' overrides nothing

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':qr_code_scanner:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use alternative [mobile_scanner](https://pub.dev/packages/mobile_scanner). this library doesn't work in Flutter 3.0. or else
if you want to use qr_code_scanner library, that is not the official creator repo but you can use it.

```
dependency_overrides:
    qr_code_scanner:
        git:
            url: https://github.com/X-SLAYER/qr_code_scanner.git
            ref: flutter-beta
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you think they are adding support to the 3.0 version soon? It's been 3 months since the last version came out but still, it's the most popular qr code lib in pub.dev for what I've seen

Comment: @MatheusMelo if you want to use qr_code_scanner add this on pubspec.yaml
dependency_overrides:
    qr_code_scanner:
        git:
            url: https://github.com/X-SLAYER/qr_code_scanner.git
            ref: flutter-beta

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with the selected answer. The `qr_code_scanner` library is compatible with flutter 3.0.1.

1. Upgrade `qr_code_scanner` library to `1.0.0`.
2. Upgrade `flutter` to `3.0.1`.

Now you can use `qr_code_scanner` with `flutter 3.x` and no need to change whole qr code library.

https://github.com/juliuscanute/qr_code_scanner/issues/334#issuecomment-1154747946

Comment: I accepted the answer because of the comment which told me to add an overriden path to the lib.